# How to execute Multiple queries at once and if one fails another can't get executed?

Tags: mysql, sql, json

I have made one database. I normalized it to 3NF. I have 5 tables that have been normalized. Now I want to perform insert query at once on 5 tables. I am making a json service which I am going to implement in my Android Application.

Now my question is how will I execute 5 queries at once, in such a way that if one fails then other can not be get executed?

P.S. I am working with phpmyadmin. And using json.

Thanks a lot. :P

Comment: the word you are looking for is transaction.

Comment: I never used it. I will try now. Thanks for a quick response. :)

Comment: oh god It worked.. thanks.. @e4c5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap all inserts in a transaction. Basically:

```
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO ....
INSERT INTO ....
INSERT INTO ....
INSERT INTO ....
COMMIT;
```

If one of the inserts fails, all will fail.

Comment: ohk I am going to try it. Thanks for a quick answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use Transaction,

Do a `START TRANSACTION` at start of the sequence and `COMMIT` at the end. If any error occurs do `ROLLBACK`.